# Best performance for updates to table

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I have a table at a remote sql server.

I need to insert a few hundred rows every minute.

Would it be best to:

```
1. Start a transaction.
2. Insert multiple rows.
3. End transaction.
```

or

```
1. Create a text file of all transactions.
2. Import from textfile  (BULK INSERT?).
```

From my reading of the docs/web it would seem that the transaction approach does what I want in the cleanest way.

I would appreciate thoughts

Comment: This question still needs some info like `what I want in the cleanest way.` define cleanest way..is this from table to table insert or from txt files

Comment: For cleanest I mean "preferred" by MSDN/Community. It is an insert from an in-memory list in c#.

Comment: so you are reading all the values from table to a memory list in c#

Comment: if so,I prefer bulk insert

Comment: Other way round: from memory list to table